# Background call android

Tags: android, user-interface, interface, background, phone-call

I need to do background calls. I mean, I don't want to show the android call interface when the program makes a call I want to show my own interface, is there any way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment. For phone calls, it will always show the dialer screen.

Answer (score 0):

*Though it is not recommended to do*, you can achieve that by linking an `Activity` with the call.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- open activity when establishing a call -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```